# FFMPEG on Windows faststart command line with or without a +

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

So on the following wiki page i see ffmpeg tells us when using faststart for HTML5 compatibility we should use a + symbol.

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#faststartforwebvideo

```
-movflags +faststart
```

But looking at command line examples on here and other sites everyone puts it in their command line like this.

```
ffmpeg -i C:\vidtests\Wildlife.mp4 -movflags faststart C:\vidtests\Wildlife_fs.mp4
```

So my question is should it matter if the + symbol is there or not ?

Comment: Try it and see.  It's probably a typo in the documentation.  If you find that it is a typo, submit a pull request to fix the documentation.

Comment: Well i am currently using it with the + symbol but conversions still seem to work fine with no errors. So i am unsure if it does even matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It will probably work with or without the `+`.

The `+` is shown in case the behavior of `-movflags` is similar to the behavior of `-flags`. For example, using `-flags qpel`  will cause flags to be explicitly set to **only** `qpel` (while clearing any other flags), while using `-flags +qpel` will allow `qpel` to be added to the list of any non-explicitly defined flags.

However, I'm unsure if `-movflags` behaves similarly and I haven't tested; additionally, I'm unsure if there are any movflags that can get automatically set as they can with flags.

To be safe it is probably better to add the `+` as shown in the wiki article.

Comment: Thanks i will leave it with the + symbol i don't know if it will cause conversion issues if it does i will make another post.